# Show drop down if text box has value

Tags: javascript

I need to show drop down only if any value is provided in text box, other wise the drop down should be hidden. I tried the following code with javascript but it is not working. With this code, the drop down is not hidden when there no value is typed in text box field. It is showing all the time.

```
<input type="text" name="example_textbox" id="textboxId" onclick="javascript:onTextboxChange()" >

<select name="example_dropdown" id="dropdownId" >
   <option selected value="0">Select One</option>
   <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
   <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
   <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
      </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var getTextBox = document.getElementById('textboxId');
var getDropDown = document.getElementById('dropdownId');

function onTextboxChange(){
    if (getTextBox.value != null)
        {
        getDropDown.disable='false';
        //getDropDown.style.display = 'inline';
        }
    else{
        //getDropDown.style.display = 'none';
        getDropDown.disable='false';
    }
}
```

Any suggestion what should I do to make it work?

Comment: put alert(getTextBox.value); to the beginning of your function and see what the value is. most probably it is '', in other terms, empty string, but not null.

Comment: btw, using style.display is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you don't need the "javascript" part in the handler:

```
<input type="text" name="example_textbox" id="textboxId" onclick="onTextboxChange()" >
```

You probably also want to check against an empty string and not just `null` as well:

```
if (getTextBox.value != null && getTextBox.value != '')
```

I'm not sure about a `disable` property (not to mention both conditions set it to the same value), but your styling changes work:

```
if (getTextBox.value != null && getTextBox.value != '') {
    getDropDown.style.display = 'inline';
} else {
    getDropDown.style.display = 'none';
}
```

With those changes in place, it [seems to be working](https://jsfiddle.net/k8gugs47/).  Though it's strange that this is happening on a *click* event in an `input`.  Maybe you meant the *change* event?  Or even the *keyup* event?

Comment: I would just add that when you choose an event to watch for, if you want instant reaction to the first character in the input, you won't be able to use change. The change event doesn't fire until the edit is complete (i.e., focus is lost).

Comment: I added the condition checking as you suggested. Now, what is happening is like you are showing in fiddle, both textbox and dropdown shows up when form is loaded, but when I click on text box the drop down hides again. I don't need to show the drop down until I click on text box to enter value.The drop down should not be hidden when I try to enter value. Any suggestion?

Comment: @TechPro: Style it to be hidden by default.  Either using CSS, or an inline style.  For example: `<select name="example_dropdown" id="dropdownId" style="display:none;">`

Comment: @David: I could hide the drop down when the form loads as you suggested. Now the only issue is, when I type value the dropdown doesn't show up itself. I need to click on filled textbox again to make dropdown to show. Is there any way, after I type the value in text box, the dropdown appears without needing to click on text box again?

Comment: @TechPro: Use a different event besides click.  I mentioned a couple options in the answer.

Comment: @David: Your answer worked for me. I used onchange event. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the function with the oninput event of the input-box

Also you need to hide the dropdown initially on the page-load.

```js
var getTextBox = document.getElementById('textboxId');
var getDropDown = document.getElementById('dropdownId');

onTextboxChange();

function onTextboxChange() {
 if (getTextBox.value != null && getTextBox.value != '') {
  getDropDown.style.display = 'inline-block';
 } else {
  getDropDown.style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

```css
#textboxId {
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:10px;
}
select {
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:250px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="example_textbox" id="textboxId" oninput="onTextboxChange()">
<select name="example_dropdown" id="dropdownId">
 <option selected value="0">Select One</option>
 <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
 <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
 <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
</select>
```